# Unknown Error when login with facebook

Tags: nopcommerce

When I'm going to sign in with Facebook (I have taken Facebook plugin from nop- commerce) it's throwing unknown error because return url is null.
How to solve it?

Comment: Please add code you've already tried. Be more specific.

Comment: i have taken the nopcommerce facebook plugin so no need to write a code just i have to set the credentials from admin side...

Comment: You used the `asp.net-mvc` tag which means you wrote an ASP.NET MVC application. Post the code that raised the error and the full exception. If you didn't, but just added a plugin to nopcommerce, remove the unrelated tag and add the appropriate one. You still need to provide an *actual* error message and logs. Plugins don't fail with "unknown error" without writing something to a log.